# string manipulation in PHP: replace only the first occurrence of a word in a string

Tags: php, string

what to do if I want to replace only the first occurrence of a word in a string.
eg: I want to change the first occurrence of heelo in a string with kiran.

```
input string == **"hello world i am a noob hello to all"**
output string == **"kiran world i am a noob hello to all"**
```

the str_replace is not working.

Comment: Please post your code. What do you mean exactly by 'not working'?

Comment: What means "is not working"? And what have you tried yet?

Comment: str_replace is changing both occurance of "hello". i just need to replace the first 'hello' with 'kiran'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `preg_replace`. The 4th arugment of this functions allows you to set how many times a replacement should occur.

```
$output = preg_replace( "/$find/", $replace, $input, 1 );
```

If you don't want regular expression meta-characters to be interpretted in the search string, use:

```
$output = preg_replace( "/\\Q$find\\E/", $replace, $input, 1 );
```

Comment: What if both hello and kiran are stored in strings.
say 
$find='hello';
$replace='kiran';
$input='hello world i am a noob hello to all';

Comment: I used the preg_replace('/' + $find + '/', $replace, $input, 1); But it is showing the error "Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash in C:\wamp\www\test\e.php" on that line

Comment: I've updated my answer to account for the case you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`stripos()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php) and [`substr_replace()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr-replace.php):

```
$str = "hello world i am a noob hello to all";
$needle = 'hello';
echo substr_replace($str, 'kiran', stripos($needle, $str), strlen($needle));
```

gives

```
kiran world i am a noob hello to all
```

---

`stripos()` gives the index of the first occurrence of a substring (case insensitive) and `substr_replace()` replace the substring at index `i` and length `n` by the given argument.